# How will craftily increasing Goodwill (by decreasing Assets) make your Income Statement look better?

Tags: balance-sheet

I try read Balance Sheets for investing, and I thought of this trick.

What company directors can do is: they can say, you know, we need to write these assets
down. We need to mark them down actually. The stock I'm buying in the target isn't worth as much
as they say  it's worth. The debt book isn't worth what they say it's worth. So what they do is: they find the excuse to
decrease this number [Assets]. Let's say the purchase price of $100, but the directors can find a way to get that number down to $75. That obviously increases goodwill to $25. We've just said: well people can ignore goodwill. Stick it on the balance sheet.  Worry about impairing it later. But that's a brilliant trick because basically what the directors have done is, to tuck in a little $5 provision (as it's called), a little bit of cushion in there, which (if the company 
they've just bought doesn't perform as well as they expect after the acquisition date) they'll release back
into the profit and loss account.

Without going through the sort of nitty-gritty accounting, writing down the assets you are buying allows the predator's 
directors to put a little bit of cushioning in the accounts for use later.  So it can really (if they get it wrong, if they can't run the business post acquisition) there's a little bit of bounce in there, ready to be released back into the profit loss account to help them out.

1. What entry in the Income Statement would that $5 cushion boost?
2. Then how does this $5 cushion assist? Please see the title of this post.

Answer (score 7):

I think you misunderstand how goodwill works (or I'm not following your example). Goodwill is the amount paid for an asset over and above it's book (nor market) value. It's not something that gets "manufactured" - it serves an actual accounting purpose.

Say a company is looking to buy another company that has $25 Million in assets and $15 Million in liabilities on their balance sheet. The company then has a book (not market) value of $10 Million, but the *market value* (value of future expected cash flows) is $15 Million. The Assets and liabilities get absorbed into the buying companies balance sheet, which leaves a $5 Million imbalance (they paid $15 Million but only added $10 Million to their equity). So the remaining $5 Million is counted as "goodwill".

From then on, the main impact goodwill has on the income statement is if it becomes *impaired*, which happens when the market (not book) value of the assets that were purchased decreases. Rather then decreasing the book value of the assets themselves, any goodwill attached to those assets is first decreased. Once goodwill is gone, then the book value of the assets may be subject to impairment.  That decrease in goodwill is a non-cash expense, which is reflected on the income statement.